# Fail to install R kernel for Jupyter in Mac

Tags: r, macos, kernel, jupyter

I use the following lines:

```
install.packages('devtools')
devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')
```

but get warnings:

- installing *source* package ‘IRkernel’ ...
  Warning in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) :
  unknown timezone 'default/America/Los_Angeles'
  ** R
  ** inst
  ** tests
  ** preparing package for lazy loading
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  Warning: running command '/usr/bin/otool -L /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/pbdZMQ/libs/pbdZMQ.so' had status 1
  Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pbdZMQ', details:
  call: if (org != fn.libzmq.4.dylib) {
  error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘IRkernel’
- removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/IRkernel’

I try to solve this problem by

```
xcode-select --install
```

but get

```
Error: object 'xcode' not found
```

Comment: So what version of Xcode do you have (if any)? You do need it to compile packages from github since they are typically not provided as binaries. (It's not something that Apple provides standard.)

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but this just happened to me and I got the

`Error: object 'xcode' not found`

because I was still running R in Terminal. Make sure you quit R with

`quit()`

and then run

`xcode-select --install`

again (using Bash/Terminal, not R from within Terminal).